# Order by random in Sanity.io GROQ query not working?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, sanity, groq

Sanity.io is awesome! But as I'm just beginning, I cannot find some things yet I know in e.g. MySQL.
According to the GROQ [cheat sheet](https://www.sanity.io/docs/data-store/query-cheat-sheet) I should be able to randomly sort and slice (LIMIT + OFFSET in MySQL) by giving this query:

```
  // BEWARE! This returns 10 random documents, ordered ascendingly by _createdAt
  *[_type == "movie"][0..9] | order(_createdAt asc)
```

However this does not randomly sort. The comment doesn't make sense also, because I would expect this to just pick the first 10 items based on creation time.

Anyone found out yet how to sort randomly? And, while we're at it, can I sort randomly with a seed? In MySQL `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY RAND(351);` would do just that

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is using random somewhat colloquially – `random` here just means non-determined, not randomly sorted.